# Why if using hash in router v4 react , it do not render correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

midtrans.herokuapp.com but when i'm using anchor link `#`, and  it do not render the section completely if you access the link from another page , here is the screenshot :

the normal UI :
[image]

The ui if access the page from another page

[image]
My code :

## Routing.js

```
class Routing extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
         <Switch>
             <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>       
             <Route name="home-page" path="/home"  handler={Home} component={Home} />
            <Route path="/index" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/client" component={Client} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/features" component={Feature} />
            <Route path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />
            <Route path="/faq" component={FAQ} />
          </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

## My Navigation Code

```
<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'>
  <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
    <li><Link to="features">Features</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="home#clients">Clients</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="faq">Support</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="contact">Contact</Link></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your link needs to be `/features`,  `/clients` etc for the Link component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri hi, i've already do as your advice and it navigate to `clients` section but still the component do not show ,

Comment: are the Link components directly since a connected Route component

Comment: yes ,i'm do `import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';` when i want to called the link , here'is the detail https://imgur.com/a/8X1lu

Comment: Why not simply use `Link` from `react-router-dom`

Comment: yes i've do that to , but still my ui not loaded/rendered correctly , you can check it through https://selly-midtrans.herokuapp.com/ , if you click `clients` menu when you're in index/home it will scroll down to `client` section. but if you're in other page eg: support , faq or feature then you click `clients` menu it do not show the ui as the index page does

Comment: one more thing you need to wrap the component that uses `Link` with withRouter